# Given $\sin x=3/4$ and $\pi/2<x<\pi$, find $\sin(x+\pi/6)$

Tags: trigonometry

> Given $\sin x=3/4$ and $\pi/2<x<\pi$, find $\sin(x+\pi/6)$.

I have been trying to calculate this question. My current working out is as follows:

$\sin\theta = 3/4$

$\pi/2 < \theta < \pi$

$$\begin{align}\sin(\theta+\pi/6)&=\sin\theta.\cos\pi/6 +\cos\theta.\sin\pi/6\\&=3/4.\sqrt{3}/2+\cos\theta.1/2\\&=(3.\sqrt{3}+4\cos\theta)/8\end{align}$$

The answer is:
$(3.\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7})/8$

However I do not know how to get to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

We have $$\sin\left(x+\frac\pi6\right)=\sin x\cos\frac\pi6+\sin\frac\pi6\cos x=\frac34\cdot\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac12\cos x$$ and since $$\sin x=\frac34=\frac3{\sqrt{3^2+(\sqrt7)^2}}$$ we know that $x>\pi/2$ so it means that by Pythagoras, $$\cos x=\frac{-\sqrt7}{\sqrt{3^2+(\sqrt7)^2}}=-\frac{\sqrt7}4$$ so the answer is $$\frac{3\sqrt3}8-\frac{\sqrt7}8$$

Comment: Close! We need to use the fact that $x$ lies in the second quadrant.

Comment: @JohnBrevik Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Easy mistake to make! But maybe you could elaborate on your answer a bit for the OP and any other trig students. You are really using $sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ and then getting a $\pm$ that you need to resolve. Cheers.

Comment: @JohnBrevik For the negative sign, I'm rather using the fact that $\cos$ is below that $x$-axis between $(\pi/2,3\pi/2)$. But for Pythagoras, it's just a right triangle. I've used a more geometric method, instead of rearranging the trig identity.

Comment: OK, I see your point.